# What is the single word for this style of mixing?

Tags: single-word-requests

> While mixing tea with sugar, We take two glasses, we pour tea in one
>   glass & put sugar in other one. we mix them by pouring tea to another
>   glass with **One glass is held high above the other when pouring**.
>   But be careful, Tea may fall on your hand with this heights.

I seen people doing this stunt very carefully & also looks dangerous act to me.

What is the single word for this style of mixing?

Comment: I don't know about tea and sugar, but there is a Spanish hard apple cider, _sidra_ or sometimes _sidra natural_, from the Asturias region of Spain, which is traditionally poured in a manner like you describe. I am not a native Spanish speaker, so I defer to others with more knowledge. But the Spanish word or phrases I have seen to describe the pouring technique are _escanciar, escanciada, or escanciar un culín._

Comment: Are you referring to ['*pulled tea*'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teh_tarik)? It's a literal translation from the Malay(?) term *teh tarik*.

Comment: Please read [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity?cb=1).

Comment: I have seen this pouring back and forth in Indian restaurants, to bring out the flavors in very hot Masala tea and Madras coffee, and to cool them.

Comment: FWIW: Apart from being customary (e.g. ritual), I've always thought the practical reason, if any, was to cool the tea. And I've mostly seen it done with an empty glass, not with glass containing (only) sugar. So in my understanding (assumptions) it is not about *mixing* at all.

Comment: vertical decanting?

Comment: the 'high altitude' pour? and another: the 'harmony pour'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Pouring from a height"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Pouring%20from%20a%20height)  seems to be an accepted terminology;  I don't think there's a single word for it.

Comment: agree,  no 'single word'

Answer (score 1):

In the Navy, it is called "boxing your coffee". This is a pun on *boxing your compass*, which in this case means to sail back and forth between known points to calibrate the magnetic compass.

> Boxing your coffee: Using two paper cups and pouring back and forth to mix creamer and/or sugar.

"Boxing your coffee" Wiktionary, Appendix: Glossary of U.S. Navy Slang
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_U.S._Navy_slang

Comment: nice ... but that is coffee.